# drawing the graph of a function f(x) = x^3 - 6x^2 + 9x - 4 in d3.js

Tags: math, d3.js

I am back at college learning maths and I want to try and use some this knowledge to create some svg with d3.js.

If I have a function f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1

I would take the following steps:

1. Find the x intercepts for when y = 0
2. Find the y intercept when x = 0
3. Find the stationary points when dy\dx = 0
4. I would then have 2 x values from point 3 to plug into the original equation.
5. I would then draw a nature table do judge the flow of the graph or curve.
6. Plot the known points from the above and sketch the graph.

Translating what I would do on pen and paper into code instructions is what I really could do with any sort of advice on the following:

1. How can I programmatically factorise point 1 of the above to find the x-intercepts for when y = 0.  I honestly do not know where to even start.
2. How would I programmatically find dy/dx and the values for the stationary points.
3. If I actually get this far then what should I use in d3 to join the points on the graph.

Comment: well your function is a curve `x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1`... what is your final goal make a curve or make a straight line

Comment: make a curve from that function

Answer (score 1):

Your other "steps" have nothing to do with d3 or plotting.

> Find the x intercepts for when y = 0

This is root finding.  Look for algorithms to help with this.

> Find the y intercept when x = 0

Easy: substitute to get `y = 1`.

> Find the stationary points when dy\dx = 0

Take the first derivative to get `3x^2 - 12x + 9` and repeat the root finding step.  Easy to get using quadratic equation.

> I would then have 2 x values from point 3 to plug into the original
>   equation. I would then draw a nature table do judge the flow of the
>   graph or curve. Plot the known points from the above and sketch the
>   graph.

I would just draw the curve.  Pick a range for x and go.

It's great to learn d3.  You'll end up with something like this:

https://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/

Answer (score 1):

For a cubic polynomial, there are closed formulas available to find all the particular points that you want (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function), and it is a sound approach to determine them.

Anyway, you will have to plot the smooth curve, which means that you will need to compute close enough points and draw a polyline that joins them.

Doing this, you are actually performing the first steps of numerical root isolation, with such an accuracy that the approximate and exact roots will be practically undistinguishable.

So an easy combined solution is to draw the curve as a polyline and find the intersections with the X axis as well as extrema using this polyline representation, rather than by means of more sophisticated methods.

This approach works for any continuous curve and is very easy to implement. So you actually draw the curve to find particular points rather than conversely as is done by analytical methods.

---

For best results on complicated curves, you can adapt the point density based on the local curvature, but this is another story.